# Conditional Probability of picking a ball out of a box

Tags: probability

> A box contains $3$ blue balls, $4$ red balls, and $8$ purple palls. $10$ balls are selected from the box without replacement. Given that the $10$th ball is purple, what is the probability that the $3$rd selected ball is blue?

The answer is $\frac{3}{14}$ but I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you have any thoughts?  (As an aside, marbles would be better... "blue balls" strikes me funny.)

Comment: To clarify Xander's comment, many on this site will refrain from answering homework type questions unless the question demonstrates that the asker has put reasonable effort into solving it themselves (I think this is actually official policy). If you edit your question to include that you will likely get more concrete responses.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we told you the first ball was purple and asked the chance the next ball is blue.  Can you do that one?  It is really the same as your problem.  You take ten balls out without looking at them.  Then you look at the tenth and find it is purple.  What balls are left?  Then you look at the third one and ask the chance it is blue.